# Unable to run the script in cron via manifest

Tags: linux, bash, cron, puppet

I am trying to deploy  a script to agents and run the script using cron every hour. When I am running `puppet agent -t` I am getting error:

> Error 400 on SERVER: Invalid parameter path on Cron[homebackup] at
>   /etc/puppet/modules/homebackup/manifests/init.pp:16 on node

In the manifest I wrote in path: `/etc/puppet/modules/homebackup/manifests/init.pp` (located at `/etc/puppet/modules/homebackup/script.sh` on the puppet master)

```
class homebackup {
file { 'scriptfile':
  ensure => 'file',
  source => 'puppet:///modules/homebackup/script.sh',
  path => '/usr/local/bin/script.sh',
  owner => 'root',
  group => 'root',
  mode => 0755,
}

cron { 'homebackup':
  ensure => 'present',
  command => "/usr/local/bin/script.sh",
  user  => root,
  minute => 0,
  require => File['scriptfile'],
}
}
```

could someone help me in finding the glitch?

---

Here is the fixed manifest

```
class homebackup {
    file { 'scriptfile':
      ensure => 'file',
      source => 'puppet:///modules/homebackup/script.sh',
      path => '/usr/local/bin/script.sh',
      owner => 'root',
      group => 'root',
      mode => 0755,
    }

    cron { 'homebackup':
      ensure => 'present',
      command => "/usr/local/bin/script.sh",
      user  => root,
      hour => "23",
      minute => absent,
      require => File['scriptfile'],
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate issue is that your file (`script.sh`) needs to be in the `files` directory under the module, i.e. `/etc/puppet/modules/homebackup/files/script.sh`. Confusingly, the `files` part of the path is *not* part of the `source` URI.

You also have another error: The `File` requirement AFAIK needs to refer to the *name* of the [file resource](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file), that is, it should be literally `require => File['script file'],`.

Your [`cron` resource](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#cron) also doesn't specify a `command` property, which is the actual command to run.

Some other tips:

- Simplify `file` resources (and references to them) by using the `path` as the title (rather than `script file`). This has the added benefit that you don't have to even specify the `path` property - [it defaults to the title](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file-attribute-path).
- Use variables for *anything* you refer to more than once, such as the title of your `file` resource.
- Use [puppet-lint](http://puppet-lint.com/) to spot some common issues.

Comment: @I0b0: Thank you for correct me. I have updated the manifest to:                  

class homebackup {
file { 'scriptfile':
  ensure => 'file',
  source => 'puppet:///modules/homebackup/script.sh',
  path => '/usr/local/bin/script.sh',
  owner => 'root',
  group => 'root',
  mode => 0755,
}

cron { 'homebackup':
  ensure => 'present',
  command => "/usr/local/bin/script.sh",
  user  => root,
  minute => 0
  require => File["scriptfile"],
}
}

Now getting error:  Error 400 on SERVER: Syntax error at 'require'; expected '}' at /etc/puppet/modules/homebackup/manifests/init.pp:16 on node

Comment: Please update your question or post another one.

Comment: I have corrected the manifest errors and puppet agent -t runs correctly. But I don't see the cron job updating. I don't see any cron jobs in "/etc/crontab". Updating question with the manifest code.

Comment: The cron job is not saved in `/etc/crontab`; run `crontab -l` to list crontab entries for the current user.